# How do i mannually enter email account and settings into windows lumia phone

Tags: 8.1, settings, microsoft-account

Hello I have two windows phone models running on windows 8.1. My Lumia 1020 (909) and Lumia 630 were okay until about two weeks ago when I started having mail exchange server problems which in turn affected windows store and some applications like whatsapp. I wiped the lumia 1020(909) and now I can't add a Microsoft account to allow me to download and access the store. I have tried everything I have read online and still nothing. And now I'm hearing some of my friends using windows lumia phones are having similar challenges.

Comment: Are you getting any error codes?

Comment: Maybe this is a server problem, not your problem. Sometimes I got failed when upgrading apps, but when I tried later, it would work.